# How to cover area while cropping rectangles with ImageMagick 7?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm stuck in how to remove (paint in white) the parts at the top of the `image1` that says `Show legend`, `Trend Chart` and the 3 small lines. I have a loop that crops several rectangles previously and would like to remove that areas while cropping each rectangle if possible.

The loop to crop in previous process is like this and I'd like to add the option that removes the areas mentioned above during this for loop if possible.

```
for ((i=0; i<$num; i++)); do
    convert $input_image -write mpr:img +delete mpr:img -crop "${coordinates[$i]}" rectangle$i.png 
done
```

**Image1.1**
[image]

**Image1.2**
[image]

- Using IM7 under Cygwin (Linux emulator)

I was thinking in create a 896x80 rectangle like `Image2` with a part transparent and the other in white to overlap over `Image1`

**Image2**
[image]

Basically is remove the parts within red line in left side of `Image3` to get the right side of `Image3`

**Image3**
[image]

**UPDATE**

I've compared  this small bars image with `Image1.1` and this is the result:

**small bar.png image**

[image]

```
$ magick compare -metric RMSE bar.png image1.1.png compare.png
10083.5 (0.153865)

$ magick compare -metric RMSE image1.1.png bar.png compare.png
8732.61 (0.133251)
```

**UPDATE2**

This is the whole magick version print:

```
$ magick -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-24 Q16-HDRI x86_64 21856 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr png tiff x xml zlib
Compiler: gcc (11.4)
```

Comment: Your post is confusing. You show one chart at the top and how to process it.  Then you show an image with multiple charts.  What does the second image with multiple charts have to do with your problem?  Can you not save the chart at the top without the top legend showing size and without the blue title area in whatever tool created the chart?

Comment: I assume your chart has constant color regions. So you should have only a limited number of colors.  You can use -connected-components to show your the ids and mean colors of each of those regions.  Then use the ids to single out a region, make all other colors transparent and crop.

Comment: "Image1" is the example of what rectangles I want to extract. The script use as input the big image `input.png` and crops the white background rectangles that contain the charts. My question is more about how to remove the areas at the top of each cropped rectangle, the areas that shows the `Image2`, that are  `Show legend`, `Trend Chart` and the 3 small lines. If my idea to overlap the  `Image3` over each cropped rectangle has some future, I'm not sure how to create that `image3`, save it in memory and overlap it over each rectangle.

Comment: I do not understand what images 1, 2, 3 and 4 have to do with either the small image at the top or the large multiple chart image at the bottom.  Please clarify.  And I do not understand what you code has to do with removing the legends?  To make it easy, please show one image that you want to process after your other processing and identify what you want to remove from that image.

Comment: Show Legend and Trend Charts are always in the same locations and have the same font size.  So just covert those areas with white by making a white image of the size you want to cover and compositing it over your cropped images at the needed locations. If it is not always at the same locations, but has the same font size, then make a template and use `compare` to locate where you need to cover and then composite a white image over those found locations.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clear. I´d like to overlap o remove that areas in the same convert command I use to crop it previously. I hope make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to process your images in Imagemagick once they have been cropped.

Input:

[image]

or

[image]

Bar Image:

[image]

```
crop_image="chart1.png"   # or use "chart2.png"
data=`magick compare -metric ncc -subimage-search \( $crop_image +repage \) bars.png null: 2>&1`
yloc=`echo "$data" | cut -d@ -f2 | cut -d, -f2`
echo $yloc
if [ $yloc -lt 40 ]; then
magick $crop_image \
\( -size 140x40 xc:white \) -geometry +0+0 -composite \
${crop_image}_whitened.png
else
magick $crop_image \
\( -size 140x40 xc:white \) -geometry +0+0 -composite \
\( -size 150x40 xc:white \) -geometry +740+0 -composite \
${crop_image}_whitened.png
fi
```

Result for first image:

[image]

Result for second image:

[image]

You can start with the large multi-chart image and do the crop for any given chart in the loop, if you want.

**ADDITION**

Here is a timing of the top part on my Mac using -metric ncc.

```
crop_image="chart1.png"   # or use "chart2.png"
time data=`magick compare -metric ncc -subimage-search \( $crop_image +repage \) bars.png null: 2>&1`
yloc=`echo "$data" | cut -d@ -f2 | cut -d, -f2`
echo $yloc
46

real    0m0.682s
user    0m0.426s
sys 0m0.129s
```

So the result is 46 for the first image and it took 0.682 seconds to process with -metric ncc.

If I use -metric rmse, it will take much longer.

```
crop_image="chart1.png"   # or use "chart2.png"
time data=`magick compare -metric rmse -subimage-search \( $crop_image +repage \) bars.png null: 2>&1`
yloc=`echo "$data" | cut -d@ -f2 | cut -d, -f2`
echo $yloc
46

real    0m8.038s
user    0m7.791s
sys 0m0.131s
```

Same result of 46, but it took 8.038 seconds.

Comment: **Show your code**.  Are you reading the large image for each crop inside the loop? If so, you might get a speed up by converting your large multi-chart image to .mpc format. Then read that image in your loop.  Writing to MPC is a bit slower than normal, but reading from it is faster, especially if you have to read it multiple times. Also be sure you use +repage after a crop when saving to PNG.

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer.  Took less than a second. Are you running in Cygwin proper window and not in a DOS window?  **What is your IM version**.  Do you have the unix tool "cut" on your system?  Do `magick chart1.png +repage chart1.png`. Then try my code in the ADDITION again.

Comment: Does it take  so long on your Ubuntu? Note that As of version 7.1.0-3, Imagemagick subimage-search compare was accelerated.  So your 7.0.10-61 is older and won't be accelerated.  But your 7.1.1-24 should work faster.

Comment: Did you do `magick chart1.png +repage chart1.png`, then try the magick compare command again on your Ubuntu system?

Comment: The point of that command was to use the new version of chart1.png in the magick compare command and see if that speeds it up for you on your Ubuntu system.

Comment: I sent the command again and waited for 39 min and needed to stop it in both systems. then I sent the same command removing the `-subimage-search` from the command and took 0.4 seconds in Ubuntu and 2.97 seconds in cygwin. I've sent this `magick compare -metric ncc \( "chart1.png" +repage \) bars.png null: 2>&1
`

Comment: Then I´ve sent `magick compare -metric rmse -subimage-search \( "chart1.png" +repage \) bars.png null: 2>&1` with `RMSE` and without `NCC` in Ubuntu and took 3.9 seconds and in cygwin 1 min

Comment: NCC should be much faster than RMSE.  Are you sure you are using the latest version of Imagemagick 7 on your Ubuntu system.  Please check with `magick -version`. Was your command with the chart1.png after doing `magick chart1.png +repage chart1.png`?  Do you have FFTW in your delegates when you do `magick -version`.  If not, that would explain it.

Comment: Yes, I've used the same `chart1.png` after doing `magick chart1.png +repage chart1.png`. I´ve updated my question. Below update2 I show the IM7 version in Ubuntu. I'm not sure what does mean `FFTW in your delegates`

Comment: You do not have FFTW delegate. That is the Fourier Transform delegate that is needed by the accelerated magick compare -metric NCC.  So that explains why your magick compare is so slow.  I am not sure you can get FFTW for Windows. But it might be available for installation on Cygwin. You might have to ask on the Imagemagick Git forum.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll check that

Answer (score 1):

Using Imagemagick 7 on a Unix-like system, assuming where you want to cover with white is always at the same location as in the image you show, change your command to

```
magick $input_image \
-crop "${coordinates[$i]}" +repage \
\( -size 140x40 xc:white \) -geometry +0+0 -composite \
\( -size 150x40 xc:white \) -geometry +740+0 -composite \
rectangle$i.png
```

Comment: Thank you. It works pretty fine. The only is that the 3 small horizontal lines are in a lower position when the `Trend Chart` appears. If a rectangle doesn´t have `Trend Chart` the 3 small horizontal lines appear about 6 pixel above.

Comment: Show an example!

Comment: Why is there a gray border at the top of the new image?

Comment: You need to use more than one command. First I think you need to make a small image of those bars. Just crop from one of your image.  Keep that for reuse in the following.   You can then do the following as one command. Use magick compare -metric rmse with an in-parenthesis  crop of the large input and the bars image to find the y position of the bars (it should be either 46 or 22) nominally.  Then you will have to use a bash if test. If the y position is less than say 40, do the command in my answer but don't do the second composite nor the crop.  Otherwise, do the command above but no crop.

Comment: I've updated the question with the command you said `magick compare -metric rmse ...` but I don't undertand the output.

Comment: You need to add -subimage-search to those commands to search for the best location of the bar image in the larger image.

Comment: I would suggest writing a script for loop over your input image to first crop the section you want. Then use the magick compare command to find the location of the bar image in the larger image. Then use an if statement to test the y coordinate. If less than 40, do not do the second composite. Otherwise, do both composites.

Comment: I've added `-subimage-search` to the command and first I looked for small bar image inside one rectangle and shown correctly the position but took about 5 minutes. Then I did the same with the large input image and has passed more than 15 minutes and still no output then I think I´ll go with your solution to fill in white by hard coded coordinates.  This is the command I've sent  `magick compare -metric RMSE -subimage-search input.png bar.png compare.png`. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: You have to crop your large multi-chart image first, then look for the bar in that image.